# Display Post Status (Closed/On Hold) in User Revisions History

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

On a user's [revisions history user page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/7945/jmac?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=2) questions look like this:

[image: Current Revision List]

Even though this was a revision to a question that is closed, it isn't showing that the question itself is closed. It also doesn't show that it's a question. Wouldn't it be nice if it matched the behavior you get when you do a search?

[image: Search Results]

As a result, you would get good information on what you actually revised, something like this:

[image: Much Better Revision List]

This would help people when skimming their revisions to try to figure out what it was they were actually revising. And would make the world a better place.